# Generate balance from Chart of Accounts

Tags: postgresql, query

I have the following tables in postgres

```
 ChartOfAccounts
| Id          | int     |
| AccountName | varchar |
| ParentId    | int     | FK self references Id
| Level       | int     | Check constraint Level >= 1 && Level <= 4

 Transactions
| Id          | int     |
| Amount      | int     |
| AccountId   | int     | FK references Accounts(Id)
```

The Chart of Accounts is a tree structure four levels deep, and a transaction will only ever reference the fourth level.

I need to be able to find the balance (sum of all trasaction amounts) of any or multiple accounts in the Chart of Accounts, no matter what level.

I've been able to come up with specific queries that will find the balance of a 4th level account and another for the 3th level, but not one that I can use for any level.

I also wonder if this query could be too slow when you have hundreds of thousands or even millions of rows in the Transactions table, but I'm guessing as long as its well indexed it will be ok.

edit:

The user can only add level 4 accounts, levels 1 to 3 are locked in and can't be changed.

I want to be able to query these balances by account_id, heres the query I currently have for level 3 account balance.

```sql
SELECT a.parent_id, SUM(t.amount) balance 
FROM transaction t 
JOIN account a ON t.account_id = a.id 
WHERE a.parent_id IN (1, 4, 7) -- IDs of the accounts which I want the balance
GROUP BY a.parent_id;
```

The expected output is

```
| account_id | balance |
| 1          | 1500    |
| 4          | -2500   |
| 7          | 550     |
```

Comment: I think your answer depends on the way you allow your users to input requests. And business requirements. Do they need to be able to enter all 4 parts of the string? Just one part? Any number of 1 to 4 parts? Open transactions, posted, or both? Users most likely want to query by account name, what if there are duplicates? (there will be). There probably is not a one size fits all solution here. Which is why you are having difficulty finding a query that works for any level.

Comment: How to ensure that there are no rings in the table `ChartOfAccounts`? FK + CHECK shown is not enough...

Comment: @Akina I've edited the question to add more context. There can't be rings since the user can only create level 4 accounts.

Comment: @JacobH I want to be able to get the balance of one or all accounts if needed by account id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a hierarchical or recursive query, like

```
with recursive
 startwith(val) as (
  select 2
  union select 5
 ), AccountTree AS (
   SELECT
      id,
      ParentId,
      id as tree_start,
      name
    FROM ChartOfAccounts
    WHERE id in (select val from startwith)
   UNION
   SELECT
      ca.id,
      ca.ParentId,
      s.tree_start,
      ca.name
     FROM ChartOfAccounts ca
     INNER JOIN AccountTree s ON s.id = ca.ParentId
)
SELECT tree_start, sum(t.amount)
  FROM AccountTree at
  left outer join Transactions t on t.AccountId = at.id
  group by tree_start
```

See this [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8S2b5wwGQL5hXTXJzroBTM/2)

Comment: Thats very close to what I need! Now I just need to be able to query by more than one single id, similar to the example I showed in my edit, which will probably require a GROUP BY clause. I've been trying to tweak your solution but without much success.

Comment: See my edited answer.  You may need to study SQL some more.  Fiddle has been updated too.

Comment: I definitely need to, I cant do much more than insert/update/delete and simple joins. Had never played with recursive before.

It doesn't work like I expected it to though, I need to results to be the individual balances of the account of id 2, and 5, not the sum of their balances.

Comment: So you need to select and group by the parent of each tree.  I'll have a look if postgresql allows that.

Comment: It seems to.  Check it out at the updated fiddle.